# Number range maintenance in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement to maintain a number range against each of the customers I have registered in my system.

The use case is that the customer gets to choose their start number range and end number range as part of the user registration process and each domain object they create in the system will be created with an auto incremented number from the range they have specified. i.e. Existing number + 1

There is also a requirement that once the numbers in the range are exhausted the numbers start cycling around.

Also they may choose to change their number range at any time.

The i.e. This logic seems very close to a typical database sequence besides the fact that the customer specifies the number range i.e. It is not a defined number range

I'd like to know if I can create a sequence dynamically perhaps as part of a stored proc where I can pass in a customer sequence name and number range?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm  ?

Comment: You can specify a start value and a max value including a "cycle" option for sequences

Comment: cycle sounds good. My question is more along the lines of create a postgres sequence on the fly perhaps using execute immediate and then perhaps storing the name of the sequence in a table

Comment: Sure, you can do that; shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can surely create sequence dynamically:

```
so=# do 'begin execute ''create sequence a cycle start with 93 maxvalue 94 minvalue 93''; end;';
DO

so=# select nextval('a'), nextval('a'),nextval('a'),nextval('a'),nextval('a');
 nextval | nextval | nextval | nextval | nextval
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
      93 |      94 |      93 |      94 |      93
```

But first - you can bloat dictionary with a too many sequences and next I dont see any need  if only user itself can spin the number - just use `update blah set num = least(maxnumber,num + 1)` or smth like it

Comment: hmmm. Yes you have made me think about this twice. You're right, at some point in time when my customer list becomes large there may be a lot of sequences.